# Pycaret - log all model tuning results in ML Flow

Tags: machine-learning, mlflow, pycaret

Is it possible to log all model tuning results, including all evaluated hyperparameter combinations, into MLflow in Pycaret? Currently, using log_experiment only logs the tuned model itself.

Alternatively, is there another convenient method to explore the tuning process and gain insight into the effects of hyperparameters?